# No version of Cypress is installed in Ci (TravisCI and CircleCI)

Tags: continuous-integration, e2e-testing, cypress

I'm getting this error in CI when updating to Cypress `3.0`, saying that Cypress is not installed, but I am running `npm install` before my `cypress run` command. The error:

```
No version of Cypress is installed in: 

/home/ubuntu/.cache/Cypress/3.0.1/Cypress

Please reinstall Cypress by running: cypress install
----------
```

Why is Cypress not finding the Cypress executable?

Here's my `circle.yml`:

```
build:
    <<: *defaults
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-npm-deps
      - run: npm install
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-npm-deps-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          paths:
            - node_modules
            - ~/.cache
            - ~/.npm
      - run: npm test
      - run: npm run build
      - persist_to_workspace:
          root: /tmp/workspace
          paths:
            - .circleci/deploy.sh
            - .circleci/e2e-test.sh
            - package.json
            - cypress.json
            - node_modules/
            - build/*
            - cypress/*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a small problem with caching `node_modules`- the post-install script that installs the Cypress binary won't be run since `node_modules/cypress` exists.

To fix this you can **flush the cache of the CI build** and everything should be solved.
This is why I recommend using [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci), since `node_modules` will get wiped every time the command is run

**Also:**
- in Circle CI 2.0, caching works differently than in `1.0` or `TravisCI` because the cache is **immutable**. You can only create another cache, never destroy and rewrite one. So, you should do caching like this:

```
- restore_cache:
  keys:
    - v1-deps-{ .Branch }-{ checksum "package.json" }
    - v1-deps-{ .Branch }
    - v1-deps
- run:
  - npm ci
- save_cache:
  key: v1-deps-{ .Branch }-{ checksum "package.json" }
  paths:
    - ~/.cache
    - ~/.npm
```